# Dropbox/dropnetrt : how to get user token/secret?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropnet

I am trying to use the dropnet api but it requires an api key/secret and a user token/secret.

```
var client = new DropNetClient("API_KEY", "API_SECRET", "USER_TOKEN", "USER_SECRET");
```

I managed to find/generate my api key/secret but I don't find how to get "user secret" and "token" to access to my own account.

Comment: You'll need to go through the OAuth flow to get an OAuth token and secret for your account. The [DropNet README](https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet) shows how to do this... where did you run into trouble?

Comment: Step 1 of your link, the functions GetToken and GetTokenAsync don't exist in dropnetrt.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed that you were using DropNetRT. The equivalent instructions are here: http://dropnet.github.io/dropnetrt.html.